# Multiple Interface implementation in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring spring-2.5.6.SEC02 and i try to wire two entities which implemented same interface. 
I want to know this spring version support multiple interface implementation.

I tried few solutions mention by guesses and still it not working.

Comment: Can you add more details? code, configuration, examples ..

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does but to resolve dependencies you need to use `@Qualifier` annotation for spring to distinguish between different implementation for injection.

For more on `@Qualifier` visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm) link.